# When did my phone power off due to low battery? Is the information recorded somewhere?

Tags: battery-life, power-on

I'd like to know when my Android phone powered down due to low battery.  Is there a log or way to see this?  I am running a new program that makes use of BlueTooth and I suspect that's the problem.  I ran the program over the weekend and when I recovered the phone, it was dead.  Of course I have no way of know if the phone died after 1 hour or 23 hours.   I'm guessing the operating system logs it somewhere.

The phone in question is a Sony Ericsson Arc, but I'm hoping the answer generally applies to all Android phones.

Answer (score 1):

You should install [Watchdog Task Manager Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zomut.watchdoglite).
It will monitor all your apps and tell you which apps are consuming the most battery and why.

For all your logging needs, install [aLogcat (free) - logcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat).

Answer (score 1):

I am using [Battery Widget Reborn](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.hubalek.android.apps.reborn.pro) ([Free Beta version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.hubalek.android.reborn.beta)).

Among its useful features is a charge/discharge graph.

[image: battery history graph]

You can use multitouch to expand or compress the graph, too. It'll show about when the battery went down to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [SystemPanelLite Task Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.systempanel). While the free version only allows live monitoring, the full version ([SystemPanel App / Task Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.systempanel.r1)) features background monitoring. Monitored data such will be recorded, and not lost on power-off. Take a look at this screenshot:

[image]

Here you can clearly see what time the app was active, how much battery it consumed, if you actively used the device during that time (or how much of the usage was done in background without you watching it), and more. Have this app running and recording in the background for a while, and then check the recorded data -- this should let you figure out which app was responsible, and also what time the device powered off.

Comment: BetterBatteryStats? :)

Comment: @t0mm13b good for techies, yes. And gives different details. *SystemPanel* is more intuitive to use for non-techies, and can give better *timed* results. *BetterBatteryStats* cannot tell you what time what event happened or when the device shut down -- at least as far as I know.